# How to specify recursive generic parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin, log4j

I just want to port the following code from Java which uses Log4j (v2.8.2):

```
ConsoleAppender appender = ConsoleAppender.newBuilder().
            withName("ConsoleAppender").build();
```

The problem is with newBuilder() method which is defined as some kind of recursive generic in log4j:

```
@PluginBuilderFactory
public static <B extends Builder<B>> B newBuilder() {
    return new Builder<B>().asBuilder();
}
```

Java code infers the generic parameter automatically which is not the case for Kotlin. Is there any solution to call this method in Kotlin?

The code I have tried in Kotlin:

```
val appender = ConsoleAppender.newBuilder().withName("ConsoleAppender").build()
```

It has the following error:

> Error:(90, 48) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter B in fun !> newBuilder(): B! Please specify it explicitly.

When the code is converted from Java automatically on paste, it sets some stub `newBuilder<B>()`, where B is not defined and I have no idea what it should be.

Comment: Could you include the code you tried and the error message you got

Comment: In the line that you tried, I don't see how exactly the compiler should infer the type. In the Java sample, you declare the type explicitly, but you don't in Kotlin.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the appender type explicitly? Like: 
`val appender : ConsoleAppender = ...`

Comment: Yes, tried it now, the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log4J seems to use a builder pattern, that in Kotlin requires every open, non-abstract class to have two builders: one generic, that can be extended by subclasses, and one non-generic that can be instantiated.

Since you probably do not want to modify Log4J, I would consider using reflection:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val builder = ConsoleAppender::class.java.getMethod("newBuilder").invoke(null) as ConsoleAppender.Builder<*>
    val appender = builder.withName("ConsoleAppender").build()
    println(appender.name)
}
```

See my answer at [discuss.kotlinlang.org](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org):

[Recursive generic in Builder pattern](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/recursive-generic-in-builder-pattern/7369)

Comment: Ended up with using this solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

I found wait how to resolve this for log4j2 configuration, please see sample:

```
// create concrete type just to call method
// however, we should not use it, because of possible runtime casting issues
private class ConsoleBuilder : ConsoleAppender.Builder<ConsoleBuilder>()

private fun createAppender(configuration: Configuration): ConsoleAppender {
    // hide our temporary class immediately, to avoid runtime type casting issue
    return (ConsoleAppender.newBuilder<ConsoleBuilder>() as ConsoleAppender.Builder<ConsoleBuilder>).apply {
        withName("MyAppender")
        setConfiguration(configuration)
    }.build()
}
```

Comment: I checked this solution, it works. But I am in doubt about this hack with type casting exception which is thrown if the casted expression is assigned to a builder variable. Is this compiler implementation dependent? Is it guaranteed to be working on the future versions?